# Countdown timer in javascript for each row of table in html

Tags: javascript

```
    var count = Number(sessionStorage.getItem('count')) || 3600;

    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
    function timer() {
    count = count - 1;
    sessionStorage.setItem('count', count)
    if (count == -1) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }

    var seconds = count % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    hours %= 60;

    var time_str = hours + ":h " + minutes + ":m " + seconds + ":s";
    //document.cookie = 'time_str = hours + ":h " + minutes + ":m " +     seconds + ":s"; expires=Thu, 26 March 20:47:11 UTC; path=/'

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.timer'), function (el ) { el.innerHTML = time_str; });
}
```

Above is my javascript code for countdown timer. This works fine, but it doesn't stop after   "0h:0m:0s" time. it start counting in negative.

Comment: Works for me. (Just ran your code in another window, minus the `Array.forEach` bit...

Comment: I am using this timer for multiple rows, thats why i am using Array

Comment: let me try without array :)

Comment: I don't think that would cause any problems since those lines execute after you clear your interval, just pointing out that I tested this with an initial value of 5 and after it counted to 0, it stopped running. The only part I *didn't* keep in was the Array.forEach bit because I don't have your HTML ;)

Comment: I try to do without array.forEach, but timer doesn't appear after that. Here is my html code https://dpaste.de/efDf. and script is here : https://dpaste.de/VHs7

Comment: @brianvaughn please have a look over these paste for html code and script code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your code that works for me:

```
var count = 5;
var counter = setInterval(hockeytimer, 1000);

function hockeytimer() {
  count = count - 1;
  sessionStorage.setItem('count', count);

  if (count == -1) {
    clearInterval(counter);
    return;
  }

  var seconds = count % 60;
  var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
  var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
  minutes %= 60;
  hours %= 60;

  if (hours === 0 && minutes === 0  && seconds === 0 ) {
    var table = document.getElementById("hockeyt");
    while (table.rows.length > 0 ) {
      table.deleteRow();
    }
  }

  var time_str = hours + ":h " + minutes + ":m " + seconds + ":s";

  var timerCells = document.querySelectorAll('.hockeytimer');

  for (var i = 0; i < timerCells.length; i++) {
    var timerCell = timerCells[i];
    timerCell.innerHTML = time_str;
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ceboqi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: this is works better, but timer stop at last second, and reset when refresh the page :)

Comment: The timer resets when you refresh the page because I removed the `localStorage` code (for clarity). I was just trying to show you how to prevent the timer from counting negative, as your original question was about.